# Tightvnc on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't start gnome-session

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-20.04, tightvnc

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and tightvncserver however, when I connect to the desktop, I see a grey desktop. I have tried some ideas to manually start gnome-session in the xstartup file, but wasn't able to fix that. The original configuration can be seen below.

```
$ cat xstartup
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession

$ dpkg -l | grep vnc
ii  libvncclient1:amd64         0.9.12+dfsg-9ubuntu0.2      amd64        API to write one's own VNC server - client library
ii  remmina-plugin-vnc:amd64    1.4.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1        amd64        VNC plugin for Remmina
ii  tightvncserver       

$ vncserver -geometry 1300x900 :1
New 'X' desktop is Frontend:1
Starting applications specified in /home/mahmood/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/mahmood/.vnc/Frontend:1.log
```

The result is shown below

[image]

Any idea to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution but I do know that I have the same problem. The cause is probably d-bus because it's always d-bus that messes up gnome.

Looking in ~/.vnc/ at your vnc server log files will give you a clue.

gnome-session-binary[257100]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using similar methods and tutorials online, but the only thing that worked for me is to download the latest stable version of TIGERVNC (not TIGHTVNC) and install it and configure it according to the instructions in the HOWTO.md for that release.

At the time of writing this, the stable version was 1.12 and setup was breeze.

1. Install tigervnc from the .deb file (for good reason Ubuntu repos do not use the latest version)
2. Add the users in a list in the `/etc/vncserver.users` file
3. Log in as the user and set a VNC passwd using vncpasswd command
4. Setup your firewall to allow the vnc-server service through
5. Enable the `vncserver:@.service` if you want to start the VNC server at system start.

That's it. TIGERVNC has updated the way we need to configure new instances of the VNC server for each new user - using the `/etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users` file. This method is so wayyyy simpler that having to maintain and edit the systemd service files like in the olds days :P

I did not even have to create the xstartup file!!!